# How to perform a pm2 start/stop/status of node js from Python script?

Tags: python, node.js, pm2

Let's say I have a Python script that will use the `subprocess` library to execute the some basic pm2 commands (for nodejs code) as shown below:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['pm2', 'status'])
```

The output then comes in a tabular format with all the services that were started/running/errored on the standard output.

How do I get only the relevant data that I want?

For example:
If I do the below:

```
subprocess.call(['pm2', 'status', 'someService'])
```

I should only get the output for `someService`

Is there a library in python that will allow me to do this? Or can I hit the pm2 using curl commands from within my Python script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some messing around I have found the answer. A simple pm2 jlist retrieves the output in JSON.

```
subprocess.call(['pm2', 'jlist'])
```